# Content not getting bold

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my react application I am getting a paragraph from my server. The paragraph has some  tags in it. When I render that in my application the text in that tag is not getting bold.

This is the paragraph or line I get

```
<b>Minister</b> the only thing that Mr Sharda
```

Here is how I render it

```
<ol> 
    {item['match'].map((v, i) => {
    return <li>{v}</li>    //v is he line i get which has <b>
    })}
</ol>
```

But when I render see the content coming up with  text written.  is not being recognized as bold. What should I do?

Comment: React doesn't render html tags this way for security reasons. You can use a library like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) to parse raw html into usable React elements. Do ensure that the raw html you have on your server doesn't have any harmful scripts.

Comment: I would recommend you to prefer markdown over html for formatted text as it is safer and serves most of the needs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Because React interprets your variable as string. What you want to do is to display your content as html.

You should use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but **beware of its usage**: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
<ol>
  {item['match'].map((v, i) => {
    return <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: v }} />;
  })}
</ol>
```